# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory Visual Studio Debugging MVC 4 solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, http-error

I am trying to debug a visual studio MVC 4 solution with the following route config content.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
        routes.MapRoute(name: "RegistrationForm", url: "{RecruitmentRegistration}/{Registration}/{id}", 
    defaults: new { controller = "RecruitmentRegistration", action = "Registration", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```

But while trying to access the controller Action method, I am facing the below listed error.

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

But when I try with the default Index action method it is working fine with the Index view getting loaded.

Below are the Controller Class contents

```
public class RecruitmentRegistrationController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /RecruitmentRegistration/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("Index");
        }

        public ActionResult Registration()
        {
            return View("RegistrationForm");
        }

    }
```

When I checked for solutions, I could find that most of the solutions are related to IIS related setting changes.But here I have not used IIS site setup and I am directly browsing from the VS2012.

Please advise.

Comment: You should try the solutions you found regarding adding items to your web.config.  Visual studio uses iis express.

Comment: Found out the issue , having default values in URL did the trick, removed the values.